# Python print conversations based on tcp port from a capture

Tags: networking, analysis, scapy

I am trying to analyze packets from an existing capture using python scapy module.
Basically, I input a pcap file and it should list me the TimeStamp, SRCIP, DSTIP, Protocol (tcp/udp), SRCPort,DSTPort, and list of TCP Options if possible.

I tried a basic scapy script to load a pcap and try to print using pkt.conversations() but I get the following error.

```
>>>pkts = rdpcap('testn.pcap')
>>> pkts.conversations()
>>> /bin/sh: dot: command not found
/bin/sh: display: command not found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Learnt from documentation that conversations() does graphical display. Which is probably not what I want. I want to print the conversations on commandline like tshark does, but with scapy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the programs `dot` ([Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)) and `display` ([ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)).

Under Debian / Ubuntu / etc., running `apt-get install graphviz imagemagick` as root should be enough.